# Data transformation, almost like when you use cast and melt

Tags: r, transformation, reshape2

I don't know how to name this data transformation neither know if there exists some kind of function to use

My data has this shape:

```
    rank  abbrv     country  eci_value delta  year
   (int) (fctr)      (fctr)      (dbl) (int) (int)
1     30    BRA      Brazil  0.5588656     2  1995
2     47    URY     Uruguay  0.2098838   -14  1995
3     52    PAN      Panama  0.1164776     2  1995
4     56    ARG   Argentina  0.0013733     7  1995
5     58    VEN   Venezuela -0.0329851    11  1995
6     64    COL    Colombia -0.2216275    -2  1995
```

And I want a data frame with just the information provided by "year, "rank" and country presented in this way:

```
country     1995      1996      1997      1998      ...
Peru      rank1995  rank1996  rank1997  rank1998    ...
Brazil    rank1995  rank1996  rank1997  rank1998    ...
Chile     rank1995  rank1996  rank1997  rank1998    ...
...         ...       ...        ...      ...
```

The var "year" ranges from 1995 to 2014 and the rank varies each year

I've thought of using a melt and dcast functions from reshape2 package... but nothing useful goes out.

Thanks

Comment: Did `dcast(yourdata, country ~ year, value.var = "rank")` not work for you?

Comment: Do you really want `rank1995` for `Brazil` in the `1995` column or the value 30 ?

Comment: Omg, I never thought of using dcast without melt. It worked! Thanks!  @steveb yeah what I wanted was the value 30.

Comment: You can also check out `tidyr`.  Something like `df %>% select(country, year, rank) %>% spread(year, rank)`.  Does this work for you or do you prefer `dcast` and `melt` ?

Comment: That's also an interesting package @steveb, thanks!

Comment: @mclzc FYI, the `select` and `%>%` are from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you.  Here is an example using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, using your small sample above (you will have to test on a larger data set or provide one).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df
#  rank abbrv   country  eci_value delta year
#1   30   BRA    Brazil  0.5588656     2 1995
#2   47   URY   Uruguay  0.2098838   -14 1995
#3   52   PAN    Panama  0.1164776     2 1995
#4   56   ARG Argentina  0.0013733     7 1995
#5   58   VEN Venezuela -0.0329851    11 1995
#6   64   COL  Colombia -0.2216275    -2 1995

df %>% select(country, year, rank) %>% spread(year, rank)
#    country 1995
#1 Argentina   56
#2    Brazil   30
#3  Colombia   64
#4    Panama   52
#5   Uruguay   47
#6 Venezuela   58
```